# Migration of a question have lost me ownership?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I originally posted a question on Serverfault: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/478828/best-selection-of-tansfer-method-of-digital-evidence?noredirect=1

It was later migrated by site admins to Security Space: 
[What do I need to be aware of to select a transfer method for digital forensic data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30912/what-do-i-need-to-be-aware-of-to-select-a-transfer-method-for-digital-forensic-d)

The problem is that I had been using two different accounts (two different emails) one for Security and other for SF. Now, even my accounts seems to be merged. I cannot control the question as it's still posted under the old name. I can only edit as a user not as OWNER.

Without the control, I cannot accept any answers or provide to users who have responded to me.